# How to delete a source map script

Tags: javascript, node.js, source-maps, devtools, nwjs

For a hobby project I'd like to load and debug code in [NW.js](https://nwjs.io/) (chromium based node-webkit)
dynamically. I learned that I can have dynamically created functions show up in the devtools sources list by appending it with a certain formatted comment (`//# sourceURL=scriptname.js;`).

If there is a way to add dynamically created code to the [source map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Debug_eval_sources),
then there probably also has to be a way to remove it from there again (except the manual way). Am I unaware of some existing devtools source-map API that let's me delete these sources programmatically?

Comment: Do you mean Chrome Dev tools?